# Convert .ttf file to .png

Tags: libgdx, sprite

Is there any way to convert a TTF to PNG files? Or any other method to create Sprite out of TTF file in LIBGDX framework? Is there any application available for it?

Answer (score 3):

### Before running

LibGDX has a built-in tool in the `gdx-tools`project called Hiero. Just run that project as a java application, and when asked which class to run, choose that one. It lets you take a .ttf file and render it the characters you need (in a size given in pixels), plus it generates a file that contains information about where each character is on the texture. In the program, it's very simple to initialize and use:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font/font.fnt"));
...
font.draw(spriteBatch, "Text to output", coordX, coordY);
```

(font.fnt is the file containing the texture positions and other relevant information, it also refers to the .png which is created in the same folder by default.)

You can take a look at the `BitmapFont` documentation [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html).

### During runtime

A disadvantage of Hiero is that bitmap fonts don't really scale well, so they can look quite bad on different screen resolutions.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675007/how-to-draw-smooth-text-in-libgdx/15147030#15147030) to a related question:

> One solution is to use the FreeType extension to libgdx, as described [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300). This allows you to generate a bitmap font on the fly from a .ttf font. Typically you would do this at startup time once you know the target resolution.

I haven't personally used it, but it seems like something worth checking out. It looks very simple as well - the example code in the linked answer is 5 lines long.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution to the same problem(TTF to PNG) which I faced too.

Follow the below steps,

**1. Convert TTF to SVG**

Use [TTF to SVG](https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-svg) conversion tool to convert your custom or downloaded TTF file to SVG file

**2. Convert SVG to PNG/PDF/TTF:**

Goto [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select), in the top left corner, there will be button to **Import Icons**, click and upload your **converted** SVG file.

In the bottom bar, there will be an option "**Generate SVG & More**" as in the below image, click on it

[image]

Next, Click the *Settings* gear icon near "**Download**" option to override size, output formats(PDF,PNG,etc.,) and then close the Settings

[image]

Now click download to get the outputs into a single zip file !!!

Answer (score 0):

A ttf is a true-type font. It is not a picture, but a vectoric character set. You can't convert it to a picture simply with a tool.

If you want to view/manipulate ttf files, you can do this with ttf editing tools, for example fontforge ( http://fontforge.sourceforge.net ).

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old question, but I found the following batch file works with ImageMagick 7:

```
@ECHO OFF
set f=wingding.TTF
set ps=800
set bg=white
set ext=png
set s=600x600
set alpha=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W Z Y Z
set num=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
For %%X in (%alpha% %num%) do (
convert -font %f% -pointsize %ps% -size %s% -background %bg% label:%%X 
%%X.%ext%)
pause
exit
```

NOTE: This conversion only works with a limited selection of font characters. It works well for all capital letters. Just install ImageMagick and make sure it is in your environment path. Include "legacy" commands in your installation.