# Distance field font in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to rendering smooth scalable bitmap fonts. After checking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675007/how-to-draw-smooth-text-in-libgdx) one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891134/1072678) mentioned using distance field fonts.

I'm doing exactly as mentioned in [LibGDX wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts) about distance filed fonts. However I can't get it working. Fonts are rendered hazy.

[image: example preview]

Here's the code I used to generate this output

```java
public class FontRenderTest implements ApplicationListener {
private Texture texture;
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
private BitmapFont font;

@Override
public void create() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Raleway.png"), true); // true enables mipmaps
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.Linear); // linear filtering in nearest mipmap image

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Raleway.fnt"), new TextureRegion(texture), false);
}


@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    font.draw(spriteBatch, "This is hazy !!", 100, 150);
    spriteBatch.end();

}
}
```

I'm not sure if I properly understand the function of distance field font. If anyone could explain how to render font smooth.

Comment: You're rendering the distance-field directly, instead of calculating the distance to the closet point on the edge. You need a fragment shader to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it needs a shader and if I recall right the shaders require GL20. As it said in the wiki you would need .frag and .vert files. I modified your code with the help from this Libgdx test: http://git.io/-yAmNg .

[image: It looks like this with different smoothing.]

It looks like this with different smoothing.

```java
public class FontRenderTest implements ApplicationListener {                                                                
private Texture texture;                                                                                                    
private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;                                                                                            
private BitmapFont font;                                                                                                    
private DistanceFieldShader distanceFieldShader;                                                                            
private static class DistanceFieldShader extends ShaderProgram {                                                            
    public DistanceFieldShader () {                                                                                         
        // The vert and frag files are copied from http://git.io/yK63lQ (vert) and http://git.io/hAcw9Q (the frag)          
        super(Gdx.files.internal("data/shaders/distancefield.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("data/shaders/distancefield.frag"));
        if (!isCompiled()) {                                                                                                
            throw new RuntimeException("Shader compilation failed:\n" + getLog());                                          
        }                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                       

    /** @param smoothing a value between 0 and 1 */                                                                         
    public void setSmoothing (float smoothing) {                                                                            
        float delta = 0.5f * MathUtils.clamp(smoothing, 0, 1);                                                              
        setUniformf("u_lower", 0.5f - delta);                                                                               
        setUniformf("u_upper", 0.5f + delta);                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                           
    @Override                                                                                                                   
    public void create() {                                                                                                      
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();                                                                                        

        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("hiero.png"), true); // true enables mipmaps                           
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.Linear); // linear filtering in nearest mipmap image 

        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("hiero.fnt"), new TextureRegion(texture), false);                              
        distanceFieldShader = new DistanceFieldShader();                                                                        
    }
       @Override                                                                             
   public void render() {                                                                
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);                                                  
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                                         

       spriteBatch.begin();                                                              

       spriteBatch.setShader(distanceFieldShader);                                       
       font.draw(spriteBatch, "This is pretty sharp !!", 100, 120);                      
       distanceFieldShader.setSmoothing(0f);                                             

       spriteBatch.setShader(distanceFieldShader);                                       
       font.draw(spriteBatch, "This is hazy !!", 100, 150);                              
       distanceFieldShader.setSmoothing(1f);                                             

       spriteBatch.setShader(distanceFieldShader);                                       
       font.draw(spriteBatch, "This is pretty smooth !!", 100, 180);                     
       distanceFieldShader.setSmoothing(1/2f);                                           

       spriteBatch.end();                                                                

   }
```

Comment: I thought i can use this technique without a shader using GL10.

Comment: Unfortunately all the updated code examples in the wiki are for GL20 since Libgdx dropped the GL10 support so I don’t know if there are any GL10 equivalent. At least I couldn’t find any.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shader created by `DistanceFieldFont.createDistanceFieldShader`.