# text in ImageTextButton bigger on higher resolution devices

Tags: libgdx

I am having some trouble specifying the size of text in ImageTextButton. I didn't found any method or property to define text size. I used the code below,but got very small text. I expect text to be bigger on higher resolution devices, since all my code is relative to the dimensions of screen. Is bitmap font the correct approach? How does one code text in ImageTextButton  to be bigger on bigger devices?

```
            font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"));
            ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle bts = new ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle();
            bts.up = ninePatchDrawable;
            bts.font=font;

            bts.fontColor= Color.WHITE;
            checkButton=new ImageTextButton("Text",bts);
            checkButton.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.2f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.01f,Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.24f,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*0.08f);

            stage.addActor(checkButton);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Comment: I was having a hard time grasping the concept of viewports. I ended up using relative layouts and so far they are working great.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to choose different keywords for google search. This solves my problem [How to draw smooth text in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675007/how-to-draw-smooth-text-in-libgdx)