# Low Resolution, Blurry TrueType font in LibGDX

Tags: java, fonts, bitmap, libgdx, truetype

I'm programming a game in LibGDX, but when I try to display some text on the screen with a TrueType font (.ttf), it comes out somewhat blurry.
[image: Low Resolution Text]
Why is this happening?

This is how I'm using the text in my code, implemented from this thread [How to draw smooth text in libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675007/how-to-draw-smooth-text-in-libgdx):

```
    stage = new Stage(viewport, game.batch);

    table = new Table();
    table.center();
    table.setFillParent(true);

    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Lato-Bold.ttf"));
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 30;
    parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
    parameter.characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

    generator.dispose();

    Label.LabelStyle labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(font, font.getColor());

    touchToStartLabel = new Label("Touch To Start", labelStyle);

    table.add(touchToStartLabel);

    stage.addActor(table);
```

Any ideas on how I can get a better rendered text? It's been bugging me for a while.

EDIT: I tried to use trilinear filtering by changing the code to this (and I'm using a FitViewport in case that's important):

```
 generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("Lato-Bold.ttf"));
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 30;
    parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
    parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
    parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
    parameter.characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
```

All I got was this (at least the squares are sharp):[image: What happened?]

Comment: If you're not using a ScreenViewport for your text, make sure it has trilinear filtering (MipMapLinearLinear, Linear) and setUseIntegerPositions(false)

Comment: On which object? `font`? I don't really get how to do it

Comment: `parameter.minFilter = TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;`  `parameter.magFilter = TextureFilter.Linear;` and `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);`

Comment: I tried, but it messed it up (I'm not using a ScreenViewport by the way). Check the edit

Comment: Also add `parameter.genMipMaps = true;`.

Comment: Thanks! It's still slightly out of focus, but it's a definite improvement over what it was before