# Best way to create incisors for BitmapFont libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am newbie to libGDX. I'm trying create incisors for a BitmapFont generated from FreeTypeFontGenerator.

[image]

The first line of text is drawn from a PNG image
The second line of text is to use FreeTypeFontGenerator to create from TTF file.

How to add aliasing to FreeTypeFontGenerator?

This is my code create FreeTypeFontGenerator:

```
public NormalFont(String fontNameFile, int size, int color, boolean useBorder, int colorBorder, boolean useShadow, int colorShadow) {
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(LibSysTem.res + "/normal/font/ttf/"+fontNameFile+".ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.setMaxTextureSize(FreeTypeFontGenerator.NO_MAXIMUM);
    parameter.size = size;
    parameter.color = new Color(color);
    if(useBorder) {
        parameter.borderWidth = 2;   
        if(mGraphics.zoomLevel < 2) {
            parameter.borderWidth = 1;   
        }
        parameter.borderColor = new Color(colorBorder);
    }
    if(useShadow) {
        parameter.shadowOffsetX = 3;
        parameter.shadowOffsetY = 3;            
        parameter.shadowColor = new Color(colorShadow);
    }   
    String textUTF8 = "áàảãạăắằẳẵặâấầẩẫậéèẻẽẹêếềểễệíìỉĩịóòỏõọôốồổỗộơớờởỡợúùủũụưứừửữựýỳỷỹỵđ";
    parameter.characters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS + textUTF8 + textUTF8.toUpperCase();
    parameter.flip = true;
    bf = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    //bf.getData().setScale(1.3f);
    generator.dispose();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675007/how-to-draw-smooth-text-in-libgdx